# ¿Problema de identificador? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi

El error es el siguiente:

> identifier not found TDato2

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type
    TDato1 = class
        campo1: string;
        campo2: string;

        dato2: TDato2;
    end;

    TDato2 = class(TDato1)
        campo3: byte;
        campo4: string;

        dato1: TDato1;
    end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: Estás intentado usar un TDato2 en TDato1 antes de que esté definida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, solo tenía que redefinir la clase.

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type
    TDato2 = class;

    TDato1 = class
        campo1: string;
        campo2: string;

        dato2: TDato2;
    end;

    TDato2 = class(TDato1)
        campo3: byte;
        campo4: string;

        dato1: TDato1;
    end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: Lo que haces no se llama re-definir la clase, sino que es una _declaración temprana_. Esto instruye al compilador sobre tu intención de declarar la clase más adelante, aceptar el identificador, y luego el compilador emitirá un error si no encuentra la declaración completa más adelante.